# If I set an expectation on a mock object, will it be used within private methods that the method I am testing calls?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, moq, unit-of-work

Methods:

```
public void MethodToTest()
{
    //Do something
    var result = PrivateMethod();
}

private UserProfile PrivateMethod(RegisterModel model)
{
    return _unitOfWork.Repository<UserProfile>().GetSingle(u => u.UserName == model.UserName);
}
```

Test:

```
public void Test()
{
    var registerModel = new RegisterModel
    {
        UserName = "admin",
        Password = "123456",
    }

    var userProfile = new UserProfile
        {
            UserId = 1,
            UserName = "admin"
        };

    var unitMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    unitMock.Setup(x => x.Repository<UserProfile>().GetSingle(u => u.UserName == registerModel.UserName)).Returns(userProfile);

    //Do the rest of the test
}
```

It is not shown here but the `Unit of Work` is injected in the constructor therefore `_unitOfWork` can be mocked. The fact that the `Unit of Work` is used in a private method, does that mean it will still hit the database even though I have mocked the object and expected the method and return value? If it does, how do I go around avoiding this? I have read that I should extract my private methods into a sepearate class, but it is already abstracted using the unit of work.

Comment: if `_unitOfWork` is your instance field, there is no problem.

Comment: Yes it is an instance field. However, when I run it, the private method returns null, even though I have set up ```_unitOfWork``` to return ```SomeObject```.

Comment: `SomeObject` doesn't happen to be null in the first place? So if you debug your test and run to the line where you have `unitMock.Setup` then SomeObject is not null?

Comment: I have updated my post to reflect my code as it occurred to me that I may be incorrecly passing in parameters or incorrectly using lambda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Fixing your issue

Change

```
unitMock.Setup(x => x.Repository<UserProfile>().GetSingle(u => u.UserName == registerModel.UserName)).Returns(userProfile);
```

to

```
unitMock.Setup(x => x.Repository<UserProfile>().GetSingle(It.IsAny<Func<UserProfile,bool>>())).Returns(userProfile);
```

The lambda expression you provided to Moq might be logically equivalent to the one you use in your production code, but it is not referentially equivalent. This means that your `GetSingle` method is being called but your lambda expression in the Mock is *not* `.Equals()` *or* `==` to the expression called in your unit under test, so the function that was setup on your Moq is never being called. As Moq stubs out methods by default, your private method is returning null because `.GetSingle(Func<T,bool>)` is returning null as it's stubbed by Moq.

### Why this happens

You can see this in action by writing the following in a C# REPL:

```
Func<bool> func1 = () => true;
Func<bool> func2 = () => true;
Console.WriteLine(func1 == func2);
// > False
Console.WriteLine(func1.Equals(func2));
// > False
```

I can safely assume you are setting your `_unitOfWork` correctly as otherwise you would be getting a `NullReferenceException`, rather than your method returning null due to the method chaining.

### Code Design

You can get around this by adding a `GetProfileByUsername(string)` method onto your repository instead, instead of allowing a lambda parameter passed to a method. Right now your code is pretty badly coupled too so I would suggest this approach. `UnitOfWork.Repository<UserProfile>().GetSingle(..)` violates Law of Demeter. Furthermore, your class has a dependency on your `IRepository<UserProfile>`, and *not* a dependency on your `UnitOfWork`. So, really, you should be mocking the `IRepository<UserProfile>` and not the `UnitOfWork` and passing *that* Mock into the class instead. If this is not the case then it is likely that your unit under test has too many responsibilities and is violating SRP *as well* as LoD :)

Comment: Thanks very informative answer. I might redesign the code in this case. Just a little detail in that I had to use ```Expression<Func<...``` for the lambda.

Comment: It is the same principle :)

Answer (score 2):

No, `_unitOfWork` becomes an instance variable. As such your private method will use that variable, it will call the method on the instance you supplied to the constructor. This can be your database implementation but your mocked class as well.

Comment: I am probably misunderstanding your wording here but 'no' as in it won't use my mocked class? Then you said it can use mocked class so I am a little confused.

Comment: It will use your mocked class, no worries. It will use whatever you put into the constructor (thus the instance field). I'm curious on your reasoning why you should extract private methods to a separate class though.

Comment: Well it was just something I read, since if you extract them into a separate class and make them public, you can mock them. Ok well as I mentioned in another comment, the private method still returns null.